# does nhibernate3 have any problem with applyfilter

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

i've just migrated from hibernate 2.1.2 to 3
now i have a problem
in one of class maps i needed  a property to be conditional in this way:

```
 public class ActivePartyConditionFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public ActivePartyConditionFilter()
    {
        WithName("ActivePartyConditionFilter")
            .AddParameter("condition", NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Int32);
    }
}

public class PartyMap : ClassMap<Party>
{
     Schema("organizationstructure");

        Id(p => p.Id);

        Map(p => p.IsApproved)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(p => p.IsActive)
            .Not.Nullable();
   ApplyFilter<ActivePartyConditionFilter>("IsActive = :condition");
}
```

i didnt have any problem with this in previous version, but in this version the line

```
 ApplyFilter<ActivePartyConditionFilter>("IsActive = :condition");
```

would make an unusable join when it wanna execute the query

Comment: I recently updated an application that uses soft-deletes on some tables with the same filter to NH3 without any issues. The only difference is IsActive is a boolean.

Comment: I have same problem in nhibernate 3, filter stop working and I got "The multi-part identifier could not be bound." error

Answer (score 0):

It has some problems. Search for filter on [Jira](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel). I cannot see from your code if any of them is causing the problem you try to describe.